# Issue with responsive table changing jquery css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have included the css to make the table responsive but this makes the td that has the datepicker to display days of the month in single lines

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
table caption {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}
table tr {
    padding: .35em;
}
table th,table td {
    padding: 625em;
    ext-align: center;
}
table th {
    font-size: .85em;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    table {
        border: 0;
    }
    table caption {
        font-ize: 1.3em;
    }
    table thead {
        border: none;
        clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
        height: 1px;
        margin: 1px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 1px;
    }
    table tr {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: .625em;
    }
    table td {
        display: block;
        font-size: .8em;
        text-align: right;
    }
    table td::before {
        content: attr(data-label);
        float: left;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    table td:last-child {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

[image: Date picker after css]

[image: Date picker before responsive css]

Comment: TD are display:block. That could be the issue.

Comment: please create a snippet, because we can't reproduce your plugin's html from your css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing every `table` element in your html, you need to be a bit more specific. Give the table you're trying to make responsive a class, ie myresponsivetable

`<table class="myresponsivetable"> ... </table>`

then adjust your CSS accordingly:

```
 table.myresponsivetable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
table.myresponsivetable caption {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}
table.myresponsivetable tr {
    padding: .35em;
}
table.myresponsivetable th,table.myresponsivetable td {
    padding: 625em;
    ext-align: center;
}
table.myresponsivetable th {
    font-size: .85em;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    table.myresponsivetable {
        border: 0;
    }
    table.myresponsivetable caption {
        font-ize: 1.3em;
    }
    table.myresponsivetable thead {
    ... and so on ...
```

This CSS will then not apply to the datepicker

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response it has really helped me.